# iOS in-app-purchase: multiple accounts

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have this concept of a single iOS app, in which multiple, independent providers can offer their goods.
So, the end user can buy something within the app, but the stuff he buys would be offered by different providers.
Ideally, the app would be configured in such a way, that when the user buys something from provider A, that provider would receive the money, rather than me, the developer, and submitter of the app. The user could also choose an offering from provider B, who, in turn, would then get the money the user pays for that specific in-app purchase.
The advantage, obviously, would be, that I don't have to deal with collecting all the money, and then transfer the right amount to the individual Providers. And having to prove these individual Providers that I give them the share that they deserve. 
Is this a scheme that directly, or indirectly would be possible in Apple's IAP scheme?

Answer (score 1):

**I have this concept of a single iOS app, in which multiple, independent providers can offer their goods.**

Taking that literally, you really need to read the in-app purchase terms of service.  You are not allowed to offer physical goods via IAP.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a native speaker. I didn't mean physical goods. For the sake of arguments: Imagine a game, developed by me, in which others can offer new levels.

Comment: Sorry, even if you are delivering virtual goods the money will all go into only one bank account.